# Prove that $n^{3/2}$ is always greater than or equal to the sum of all positive divisors of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $a_1,\dots,a_x$ be the positive divisors of $n$. Show that $\lceil n^{3/2}\rceil \geq a_1+\cdots+a_x$.

I've manage to transform that into $ \lceil a_x^{3/2}\rceil = \lceil (p_1^{q_1}p_2^{q_2}....p_k^{q_k})^{3/2} \rceil \ge (1+p_1+p_1^2+...+p_1^{q_1})(1+p_2+...+p_2^{q_2})....(1+p_k+...+p_k^{a_k}) $ sorry for my bad writing. I'm new here

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE... Any thoughts and where you are stuck on this problem ?

Comment: Well, what if $n=2$?

Comment: @Shailesh I've manage to transform that into $ a_x^{3/2} = (p_1^{q_1}p_2^{q_2}....p_k^{q_k})^{3/2} >= (1+p_1+p_1^2+...p_1^{q_1})(1+p_2+...p_2^{q_2})....(1+p_k+...p_k^{a_k}) $ sorry for my bad writing. I'm new here

Comment: Edit your question and include that. Otherwise it might get closed.

Comment: You can do this by pairing up reciprocal divisors, and nothing that USUALLY, they sum to less than n. Since there are at most sqrt(n) pairs, you are basically done. The caveat is the pair (1,n), which sums to MORE than n. But, *as long as there is another divisor*, you'll be ok.  So you can just worry about primes. All these things can be proved but that's up to you.

Comment: What are you trying to notate with $\roof$? Do you mean the ceiling function $\lceil x \rceil$?

Answer (score 2):

If
$n 
= \prod_{p | n} p^{a_p(n)}
$,
then
$\sigma(n)
= \prod_{p | n} \sigma(p^{a_p(n)})
= \prod_{p | n} \dfrac{p^{a_p(n)+1}-1}{p-1}
$.

Since both
$n^{3/2}$ and
$\sigma(n)$
are multiplicative functions,
if we can show that
$(p^{a_p(n)})^{3/2}
\ge \dfrac{p^{a_p(n)+1}-1}{p-1}
$,
we are done.

Write this as
$p^{3a/2}
\ge \dfrac{p^{a+1}-1}{p-1}
$.

Just to be a little more general,
write $c$ for $3/2$,
so this becomes
$p^{ca}
\ge \dfrac{p^{a+1}-1}{p-1}
$,
where $c > 1$.

Let's look at this
for the small primes,
since these cause the problems.

If $p=2$,
this is
$2^{ca}
\ge 2^{a+1}-1
$.
If $a=1$,
this is
$2^c
\ge 3$
or
$c 
\ge \log_2 3
\approx 1.585
$.
If $a=2$,
this is
$4^{c}
\ge 7
$
or
$c
\ge \frac{\log 7}{\log 4}
\approx 1.403
$.
The value of $c$
gets smaller for
larger $a$,
so $\log_2 3$
is the best we can do.

If $p=3$,
this is
$3^{ca}
\ge \dfrac{3^{a+1}-1}{2}
$,
or
$2\cdot 3^{ca}
\ge 3^{a+1}-1
$.
If we can show that
$2\cdot 3^{ca}
\ge 3^{a+1}
$,
we are done here.

This is
$2\cdot 3^{ca-a-1}
\ge 1
$
or
$\ln 2+(a(c-1)-1)\ln 3
\ge 0$.

If $a \ge 2$,
this is
$\ln 2 +(2c-3)\ln 3
\ge 0$
which is certainly true
for
$c \ge 3/2$.
This may be where the problem
got the 3/2.

If $a=1$,
this is
$\ln 2+(c-2)\ln 3
\ge 0$
or
$c
\ge 2-\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3}
\approx 1.369
$.
Again,
$\frac32$ works.

We can now assume that
$p \ge 5$.

We want
$p^{ca}
\ge \dfrac{p^{a+1}-1}{p-1}
= \dfrac{p^{a+1}-p^a+p^a-1}{p-1}
= p^a+\dfrac{p^a-1}{p-1}
$,
so if
$p^{ca} \ge 2p^a$,
we are done.

This is
$p^{a(c-1)}
\ge 2$.
Since
$p \ge 5$
and
$a \ge 1$,
this is true when
$5^{c-1}
\ge 2
$
or
$c \ge 1+\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 5}
\approx 1.43
$,
so the
$3/2$
works.

So $\frac32$
works for everything
except
$n=2$,
in which case we have to use
$\log_2 3
\approx 1.585
$.

Comment: Proving $p^{3a/2}
\ge \dfrac{p^{a+1}-1}{p-1}$. If $a \ge2$, $p^{3a/2} \ge p^{a+1}>\dfrac{p^{a+1}-1}{p-1}$. If $a=1$ and $p \ge 3$, $p^{1.5}=\sqrt{p}p\ge \sqrt{2}p>p+1=\dfrac{p^{a+1}-1}{p-1}$. If $a=1$ and $p=2$, counterexample.

Comment: That's what I said: 3/2 for everything except n=2.